# Expandible ListView Make expanded group position as first visible position

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a situation here, I am Collapsing all group and keeping only one group open. But the expanded group goes out of view, I want my expanded group to be always as first visible position.

This is what I have done to collapse all views.

```
@Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
        ExpandableListView list=(ExpandableListView)mFragment.getmListCategories();
        int len = getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i != groupPosition) {
                list.collapseGroup(i);
            }
        }

    }
```

and I have tried the below to keep the expanded group visible

```
@Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, long id) {
        int h1 = mListCategories.getHeight();
        int h2 = v.getHeight();

//      mListCategories.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(groupPosition, (h1/2)-(h2/2), 00);
//      mListCategories.setSelectionFromTop(groupPosition, 0);
        Config.debug("Scroll groupPosition "+groupPosition);

//      mListCategories.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(0, v.getTop() - (v.getHeight() / 2) + (v.getHeight() / 2), 0);


        return false;
    }
```

None of them are working properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Can you try mListCategories.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition)?

Comment: I did that too. @AtulOHolic

Comment: you need to do it in onGroupExpanded method. In addition to this set android:transcriptMode="disabled" for the listview. In case this doesnt work simply try mListCategories.setSelection(groupPosition)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is in your `onGroupExpanded()` method, you can get the x and y co-ordinates of the view that is to be expanded after you have collapsed the others. Then you can call `ListView.setScroll(x,y)` to scroll to the expanded view.

Comment: Hi I have tried setScroll(x,y) but it shows blank space after scrolling. Then I have to scroll manually to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Set **android:transcriptMode="disabled"** on your ExpandableListView.

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expadableListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    />
```